Does it make sense to talk about time in absence of matter?
The equations of general relativity should predict (although I might be wrong) that in absence of mass the spacetime is everywhere flat. That is, time is the same everywhere. However, I'm not sure about what would happen in total absence of matter, including energy.
Now, I know that this is not actually possible, but I'm taking a very theoretical example. Suppose a universe without mass nor energy. My questions are:

Does it still make sense to even speak about time? If there is no event to compare, does time still exist, at least from a purely mathematical viewpoint? I'm not asking if it's useful to consider its existence, just if it still exists.
So, relating to the first question, is the existence of time independent on the existence of matter? Is time actually a physical entity, as much as matter? Does time exist without matter or vice versa?

In short, what is the modern, theoretical definition of time?
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: no, the suggested duplicate does not answer my question. In the scenario of that question, there's still energy, while I'm asking for total absence of matter in all of its forms (it's probably a very stupid question, but I'm stupid as well, so it isn't surprising).

A good reality check:  If you think something might be impossible in GR, start by asking if it's possible in Minkowski space.

spacetime is everywhere flat. That is, time is the same everywhere. Why do you think the former implies the latter?

@Elvis In this universe without energy and matter where would be you (energy and matter) personally?

By the way, do not quail. No stupid person asks such questions.

@Ghoster because I don't have a correct understanding of the principles of GR, I guess. Can you elaborate further, please?

@JanG I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly. I wouldn't be anywhere.

@Elvis That would mean you are not part of that universe. In his book The Special and the General Theory (fifth edition, 1954), http://www.relativitybook.com/resources/Einstein_space.html,
in Chapter The Concept of Space in the General Theory of Relativity, Einstein says "There is no such thing as an empty space, i.e. a space without field." With space he means spacetime.

@JanG so it isn't possible to theorize mathematically a universe without matter?

Flat spacetime has three spatial dimensions whose coordinates run from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and one temporal dimension whose coordinate runs from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Points in flat spacetime with different time coordinates are different points in spacetime, just like points with different spatial coordinates are different points.

So it isn't possible to theorize mathematically a universe without matter? It is possible. See the Wikipedia article on Minkowski space, which doesn’t even contain the word “matter”.

@Ghoster Minkowski is the spacetime of SR and I talked about the spacetime of GR. In the link I have quoted Einstein himself explains why these two are different. To my knowledge in the GR Minkowski is only the local tangent space.

@Elvis It is of course possible but it would be mathematics not physics. Your universe would be a mathematical object. Physics is mathematics but mit units. A physical quantity is product of number (mathematics) and the unit (physics). Think of meter stick and the length measurement. If you say 1 meter it means you have got a material object and call it meter (unit). So a universe without matter and energy is not physical.

@Ghoster Einstein writes:"....in accordance to the special theory of relativity, space (space-time) has an existence independent of matter or field. (...). On the basis of the general theory of relativity, on the other hand, space as opposed to "what fills space", which is dependent on the co-ordinates, has no separate existence."

Your question should be reopened. It's a good one. Assuming the empty space that you're talking about is our spacetime,  just with no mass-energy, then time does exist in the same sense that space exists without any mass-energy in it. But until you inject momentum into the spacetime, that situation is identical to no spacetime existing at all.
